# Specifically for a User Control, is there a place after the constructor, but before the Loaded event where you can access properties set in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, loaded

We have an issue where our user control is initialized based on what the user sets in XAML when utilizing our control.  Currently we were using the 'Loaded' event to act on what the user had set or not.

However, the issue with using the Loaded event is another sibling of this control is using *their* loaded event to set something on ours, which isn't yet fully initialized since *our* Loaded event hasn't yet fired.  (It's a UI race condition if you will.)

Again, we can't move our code to the constructor as the WPF system hasn't yet set the properties specified by the XAML of the consumer of our control.  We can't use the Loaded event for the reasons stated above.  Initialized doesn't seem to work either.

I've also looked into ISupportsInitialize, but that's where *we* would be batch-setting the control's properties, not something externally, so that doesn't seem to be a fit either.

Thoughts?

### Update

I've since found out this is an anomaly specifically with UserControls.  They handle initialization differently.  You can find more details in my follow-up question here...

- [How can you access XAML-set properties of a UserControl during initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583196/how-can-you-initialize-a-usercontrol-based-on-user-set-properties-and-before-loa)

...but the short version is calling InitializeComponent in the constructor actually raises the Initialized event, but does so before the XAML-defined properties have actually been set.  Comment it out and the properties are now set when Initialized fires, but of course your control's UI isn't loaded! Kinda frustrating actually.

Still looking for a solution.  Code examples and more details can be found there.

Comment: Can you describe why and how you act on the `Loaded` event, i.e. what is the nature of acting on the control's properties? Perhaps there is a more WPF-y way to achieve the same. The sibling control tapping into your own event sounds very wrong, why does it do that? If it's not self-contained then you should simply fuse the two into one entity and coordinate this communication.

Comment: The sibling *doesn't' tap into my loaded event.  They are using *their* loaded event to set a property on our control which isn't yet fully set up because *our* loaded event hasn't yet fired.  Put another way, if you add a subclass of a TextBox control in your XAML and set its text property, what can be done inside the subclass *after* the text property is set, but before the Loaded event fires. Note, we can't use change notifications as the user may want default values, but we still need something before the Loaded event fires.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[Copying my answer from my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583196/how-can-you-initialize-a-usercontrol-based-on-user-set-properties-and-before-loa).]*

Awesomesausage!  I figured it out!

Normally when you receive the `Initialized` event (or are inside the `OnInitialized` override) you have access to XAML-set property values.  However, `UserControl` classes work a little differently as they depend on `InitializeComponent` being called to hydrate the UI and set the related member variables, etc.

The problem is that call is in the constructor, which in turn ends up calling `OnInitialized` (and thus raising the `Initialized` event) but that happens way before the XAML-set properties have been applied, meaning you don’t have access to them yet, which I needed.

One may think that's a good use for the `Loaded` event--to finish initialization based on those properties--but if you're performing additional initialization there, you're creating a potential race condition with your consumers in that if they subscribe to your `Loaded` event and get it before you, then in their handler try to access your control, they will be accessing an uninitialized control.

Then something occurred to me... As I showed above, if you remove the `InitializeComponent` call from the constructor, the `Initialized` event now works as you would expect, but of course your UI isn't hydrated yet since you haven't yet called `InitializeComponent`.

So what would happen if you moved that call to the beginning of the `OnInitialized` override, before the call to `base.OnInitialized`, and thus before the `Initialized` event was raised?

Yep!  That worked! :)

This way not only do you have the XAML-set properties, but you’d also have the UI fully loaded before anyone gets the `Initialized` event (let alone the `Loaded` event), which is how the `Initialized` event is supposed to be used.

Below is the revised code...

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl
{
    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.OnInitialized(e);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TestValue",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(TestControl),
        new UIPropertyMetadata("Original Value"));

    public string TestValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TestValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestValueProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

- Note: You don't need the constructor anymore unless you have a specific need to do other things there.  And if you do, just remember you can't access constituent controls by name until after the `InitializeComponent` call, but that just means you have to plan to move such name-based initialization between `InitializeComponent` and that call to `base.OnInitialize` and things will work just fine.

Comment: Wow, thank you for this.  Seems odd that this isn't the default behavior eh?

Comment: Tell me about it!  The fact it isn't even documented just makes it that much more frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

There is  the `Window.Initialized` event which comes after the constructor is called and before the `Window.Loaded` event. Properties will be set by then, but `DynamicResource` and `Binding` values won't. From the [Object Lifetime Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221.aspx) page on the MSDN website:

> Initialized  is raised first, and roughly corresponds to the initialization of the object by the call to its constructor. Because the event happens in response to initialization, you are guaranteed that all properties of the object are set. (An exception is expression usages such as dynamic resources or binding; these will be unevaluated expressions.) As a consequence of the requirement that all properties are set, the sequence of Initialized being raised by nested elements that are defined in markup appears to occur in order of deepest elements in the element tree first, then parent elements toward the root. This order is because the parent-child relationships and containment are properties, and therefore the parent cannot report initialization until the child elements that fill the property are also completely initialized.
>
> When you are writing handlers in response to the Initialized event, you must consider that there is no guarantee that all other elements in the element tree (either logical tree or visual tree) around where the handler is attached have been created, particularly parent elements. Member variables may be null, or data sources might not yet be populated by the underlying binding (even at the expression level).

Comment: See my update above.  Initialized is called when the constructor calls InitializeComponent.  The solution we found is to not call InitializeComponent in the constructor, but rather in the actual Initialize event, but before the base class's version is called.  That gives us everything we need.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Can you please put that into an answer and accept it so that this question can be set an answered?

Answer (score 2):

How coincidental that an 8 month old post is answered 2 days ago with the exact problem I am currently having (but with WinRT XAML, not WPF).

Ran into this same issue with a UserControl that contains an Image control. UserControl has a custom integer dependency property whose change handler sets the Image.Source to a new BitmapImage (the integer value determine which image to show).

Had a race condition where the image was not always being displayed properly. Very intermittent and unfortunately I published a Win 8.1 and WinPhone 8.1 app with the bug. Ugh.

Thank you for your contributions MarqueIV and Sheridanless.

Comment: Glad we could help!  Make sure to vote up both the question and answer too!  Helps improve our rep here.