# Binding OneWayToSource - Strange Behavior

Tags: c#, wpf

I have done a buch of test with `Binding Mode = OneWayToSource` lately and I still don't know why certain things happen.

As example I set a value on a `dependency property` in class constructor. Now when Binding is initalizing the `Target` property gets set to its default value. Means the `dependency property` gets set to `null` and I lose the value I initalized in `constructor`.

Why is that happening? The `Binding Mode` is not working the way the name describes it. It shall only update the `Source` and not `Target`

Here is code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

This is XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
        <local:MyCustomControl Txt="{Binding Str, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
        <Button Click="OnClick"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This is MyCustomControl:

```
    public class MyCustomControl : Control
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TxtProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Txt", typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        static MyCustomControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl)));
        }

        public MyCustomControl()
        {
           this.Txt = "123";
        }

        public string Txt
        {
           get { return (string)this.GetValue(TxtProperty); }

           set { this.SetValue(TxtProperty, value); }
        }
     }
```

This is ViewModel:

```
    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string str;

        public string Str
        {
            get { return this.str; }
            set
            {
                if (this.str != value)
                {
                    this.str = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("Str");
                }
            }
         }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null && propertyName != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     }
```

Comment: Can you show some code because I cannot replicate what you are describing

Comment: Which part didnt you get?

Comment: I got all of it, just cant replicate.

Comment: There is code. Try it out.

Comment: Have you tried setting `private string str = "123"` in your ViewModel?

Comment: The Binding mode is OneWayToSource so how will setting in Source str = 123 initalize the Target property with 123?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.Txt = "123";
```

This is *replacing* your binding with a local value. See [dependency property value precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx). You're essentially calling [`DependencyObject.SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473.aspx) when you really want [`DependencyProperty.SetCurrentValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx). In addition, you need to wait until later in the life cycle to do this, otherwise WPF will update `Str` twice: once with "123" and then again with `null`:

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInitialized(e);
    this.SetCurrentValue(TxtProperty, "123");
}
```

If you do this in your user control's constructor, it executes when WPF instantiates it, but is promptly replaced when WPF loads and deserializes and applies your BAML.

Update: Apologies, I misunderstood your exact issue but now have a repro for it, copied below. I was missing the part where you subsequently update the `DataContext`. I fixed this by setting the current value when the data context changes, but in a separate message. Otherwise, WPF neglects to forward the change onto your new data source.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SO18779291
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.setNewContext.Click += (s, e) => this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
            this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class MyCustomControl : Control
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TxtProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Txt", typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(OnTxtChanged));

        static MyCustomControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl)));
        }

        public MyCustomControl()
        {
            this.DataContextChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    this.SetCurrentValue(TxtProperty, "123");
                });
            };
        }

        public string Txt
        {
            get { return (string)this.GetValue(TxtProperty); }

            set { this.SetValue(TxtProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnTxtChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Changed: '{0}' -> '{1}'", e.OldValue, e.NewValue);
        }
    }

    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string str;

        public string Str
        {
            get { return this.str; }
            set
            {
                if (this.str != value)
                {
                    this.str = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("Str");
                }
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null && propertyName != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SO18779291.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO18779291"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:MyCustomControl Txt="{Binding Str, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
        <Button x:Name="setNewContext">New Context</Button>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Str, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: OnInitalized gets triggered only once when the control is completely initalized but what if I changed DataContext at runtime? It would again destroy the value of the dependecy property in control. Like I mentioned in my question I did a bunch of test and I also tried your approach with OnInitalized event but as soon the DataContext changes the Binding sets the value of the dependency property back to its default (which is null). That shouldnt happen though because Binding.Mode is OneWayToSource.

Comment: `DataContextChanged += (s, e) => this.SetCurrentValue(TxtProperty, "123");`

Comment: I tried that too and its not working. Try it out yourself. The value stay null. Lets not keep guessing and handling every possible case. I would like to find a good solution or at least reason why is this happening when using OneWayToSource Binding

Comment: @ninja. I did try it - it was not a guess. It works. What version of WPF are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.0 and on DataContextChanged I set current value of the Txt dependency property. The Binding does transfer the value from target to source but right after that the Binding again transfers the null value from target to source. So both are null. For me its not working and I have tried it out too. I am sitting right now in front of that wpf project.

Comment: Try change datacontext by adding a button to the stackpanel and when clicking on it you run following code this.DataContext = new MyViewModel(); See my question I edited the code there.

Comment: @ninja: updated my answer. Your point about adding a button was exactly what I missed.

Comment: To sum up you solved this by using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. But why is not wpf forwarding the value in first place? Does somebody know why is this happening? Its is a wpf bug?

Comment: btw, I would say this is a limitation of WPF. If the current value of a one-way-to-source binding isn't explicitly set, it doesn't push it to the source, even if the source itself changes. EDIT: yes, I'd say a bug. Will it ever be fixed? Fat chance I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

### Binding will work with locally set value only after initialization of target property.

> The dependency property gets set to null and I lose the value I
>   initalized in constructor.Why is that happening?

Since `InitializeComponent()` is missing in your `UserControl` ctor, and you may set `Txt` either before or after it, let's consider both cases with the presumption that `Txt` is initialized inside `InitializeComponent()`. Here initialization of `Txt` means it gets assingned the value declared in XAML.  If `Txt` is set locally beforehand, the binding from XAML would replace this value. And if it is set afterwards, the binding would take into account this value whenever it gets its chance to be evaluated, which is the case for both *TwoWay* and *OneWayToSource* bindings. (Trigger of binding evaluation will be explained later.)

To prove my theory, I did a test with three elements each with a different mode of  binding.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TwoWayStr,Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
<local:UserControl1 Txt="{Binding OneWayToSourceStr, Mode=OneWay}" />
<Button Content="{Binding OneWayStr,Mode=OneWay}"></Button>
```

However the result shows that local value is ignored in both cases. Because unlike other elements, by the time `InitializeComponent()` exits and `Initialized` event fires, properties of `UserControl` haven't been initialized yet, including `Txt`.

1. Initialization

   - (Begin) Enters `InitializeComponent()` in `Window` ctor
   - `Text` initialized and *TwoWay* binding attempt to attach binding source
   - `TextBox` Initialized
   - `UserControl` Initialized
   - `Txt` initialized and *OneWayToSource* binding attempt to attach binding source
   - `Content` initialized and *OneWay* binding attempt to attach binding source
   - `Button` Initialized
   - `Window` Initialized
   - (End) Exits `InitializeComponent()` in `Window` ctor
2. Loading/Rendering

   - (Begin) Exits `Window` ctor
   - *TwoWay* binding attempt to attach binding source if unattached
   - *OneWayToSource* binding attempt to attach binding source if unattached
   - *OneWay* binding attempt to attach binding source if unattached
   - `Window` Loaded
   - `TextBox` Loaded
   - `UserControl` Loaded
   - `Button` Loaded
   - (End) All elements Loaded
3. Post-loading

   - (Begin) All elements Loaded
   - *TwoWay* binding attempt to attach binding source if unattached
   - *OneWayToSource* binding attempt to attach binding source if unattached
   - *OneWay* binding initial attempt to attach binding source if unattached
   - (End) `Window` displayed

This special behavior of `UserControl` that properties are initialized afterwards is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580352/specifically-for-a-user-control-is-there-a-place-after-the-constructor-but-bef). If you use the method provided there, the calling of `OnInitialized` override along with the firing of `Initialized` event will be delayed until after all properties are initialized. And if you call `BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, MyCustomControl.TxtProperty)` in `OnInitialized` override or in the handler of `Initialized`, the return value will no longer be null.

At this point, it will be safe to assign the local value. But the binding evaluation will not be triggered immediately to transfer the value, because the binding source(DataContext) is still unavailable, notice the DataContext is not set until after `Window` initialization. In fact if you check `Status` property of the returned binding expression, the value is `Unattached`.

After entering Loading stage, the second attempt to attach binding source will seize the DataContext, then an evaluation will be triggered by this first attachment of binding source where value of `Txt` (in this case "123") will be transfered to source property `Str` via setter. And the status of this biniding expression now changes to `Active` which represents a resolved state of binding source.

If you weren't to use the method mentioned in that question, you can move the local value assignment after `InitializeComponent()` of Window, into `Intialized` handler of `Window` or `Loaded` handler of `Window`/`UserControl`, the result will be the same. Except if it were set in `Loaded`, local assignment will trigger an immediate evaluation, since binding source is already attached. And the one triggered by first attachment will be instead transferring default value of `Txt`.

### OneWayToSource binding evaluation triggered by change of binding source will pass default value to source property.

> What if I changed DataContext at runtime? It would again destroy the
>   value of the dependecy property in control.

From the previous segment, we've already seen two types of triggers for binding evaluation of `OneWayToSource` binding, one is target property change(if `UpdateSourceTrigger` of binding is `PropertyChanged`, which is often default), and the other is first attachment of binding source.

It seems that from the discussion in the accepted answer that you have a second question about why default value is used instead of the "current" value of `Txt` in the evaluation triggered by binding source changes. It turns out this is the designed behavior of this third type of evaluaiton trigger, which is also confirmed by the 2nd and 3rd answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398199/wpf-binding-onewaytosource-sets-source-property-to-when-the-datacontext-is-ch). By the way, I'm testing this in .Net 4.5, there is a change of evaluation process of `OneWayToSource` from 4.0 by removing the getter call after setter, but this does not change the "default value" behavior.

As a side note, for both *TwoWay* and *OneWay* binding, the evaluation triggered by first attachment and change of binding source behaves exactly the same by calling getter.

#### Extra: OneWayToSource binding will ignore changes on all levels of path

Another strange behavior of `OneWayToSource` binding that is perhaps pertaining to the topic is that although it is expected that changes of target property is not listened to, if the binding path contains more than one level, which means the target property is nested, changes to all levels up from the target property is also ignored. For example, if the binding is declared like this `Text={Binding ChildViewModel.Str, Mode=OneWayToSource}`, a change to the `ChildViewModel` property will not trigger a binding evaluation, in fact, if you trigger an evaluation by changing `Text`, `Str` setter is called on the previous `ChildViewModel` instance. This behavior makes `OneWayToSource` deviate more from the other two modes.

P.S.: I know this is an old post. But since these behaviors are still not well documented, I thought it might be helpful to anyone also trying to understand what happens.